# Accessing array elements from the array name received as a String in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a function that receives an array of Strings. These are the names of variables I'm supposed to concat together.

Something like:

```
function createArray(varNames){
  varNames.each( function(varName){
    someArray = someArray.concat(varName.items);
  });
}

createArray(["array1", "array2"]);
```

I don't know how to take a string and select the variable named after it. Any way of doing this in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends of the scope where the variable was defined. If it was defined in the global scope (inside a browser) you could access it via the `window` object.

For example:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
window['arr1']; // 1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 0):

try window[varName] - drop the .items

for example

```
function createArray(varNames,theScope){
  theScope = theScope || window;
  varNames.each( function(varName){
    someArray = someArray.concat(theScope[varName]);
  });
}
```

`createArray(["array1", "array2"]);`

if you have

`var array1=[...];`
`var array2=[...];`

or

`createArray(["array1", "array2"],myScope);`

if you have

```
var myScope = {
  "array1":[...],
  "array2":[...],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables in an array rather than passing a string.